how to set permission in google data studio report automatically or code base
I want to set permission in google data studio report automatically
(I mean google data studio not looker studio)
How can I do that?
Is it possible if I use apps script?
Are below steps possible?

write user id in google sheet
apps script read the user id and set permission in report

Please help me
I don't know what to do

Google Data Studio was rebranded as Looker Studio in 2022

Thank you so much. anyway how can I do that? please help me
